# How can I find documents which match all words in differents queries?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-7

For example with this mappings:

```json
PUT /unit-test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": { "type": "text" },
      "landlords": {
        "type": "nested", 
        "properties": {
          "name": { "type": "text" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I have this document:

```json
{ 
  "name": "T2 - Boulevard Haussmann - P429",
  "landlords": [
    { "name": "John Doe" }
  ] 
}
```

I want "boulevard hausmann" and "boulevard haussman doe" to match but not "rue haussman" or "haussman jeanne".

I cannot use `multi_match` with `"operator": "and"` because `landlords` are nested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea is to set the [copy_to](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html) mapping parameter to the `name` and `landlords.name` fields, in order to copy the values of both fields into another field (say, `names`) that you will use for your search.

So your mapping may look like:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "copy_to": "names"
      },
      "landlords": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "copy_to": "names"
          }
        }
      },
      "names": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and your search

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "names": {
        "query": "boulevard haussman doe",
        "operator": "AND"
      }
    }
  }
}
```